# Screan tearing gpu nvidia

Tags: gpu

I'm having problems with tearing the screen I'm using xububtu and I don't want to use nvidia's proprietary drive as I would solve this problem without proprietary drive and without changing the window compositor?
GPU 1050 TI

Answer (score 0):

## add this

```
 Option "Pageflip" "false"
```

in xorg configure files may help you
Xorg configure files is in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

Both Intel and Nvidia conf files

If this not working,take a look in the archwiki(link below)
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Tearing

If this not working,try to check out if vsync is enabled

```
$ glxgears
```

if fps near your display's fps number it means vsync is enabled

Comment: Hard to read, please remove unnecessary headings.

Comment: But the gpu is an nvidia and documentation asks to change an intel's configuration file

Comment: Nvidia settings (gui tools) got this options too.